# Repeaters, Switches, and Sections, Oh My

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make a form designer/builder with webapi and angularjs. I'm passing a number of fields given a form id. One of the key value pairs that is passed along is what section the field should be in. The sections are essentially a div.well that with h5{section} as the section header. The problem that I want to have 2-3 sections containing several fields but I can't seem to figure out the right way build my partial.
 [Here is a link to a JSFiddle I was working on](http://jsfiddle.net/8geat/33/)

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <div class="well" style='overflow: hidden'>
        <div ng-repeat="formfield in form.FormsFields | filter:q">
            <div ng-switch on="formfield.Field.fieldType">
                <div ng-switch-when="Txt" class="span{{formfield.spanSize}}" style="margin-left: 5px; ">
                    <label for="" class="label label-info">{{formfield.Field.label}}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" section="{{formfield.section}}" name="" id="test">
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="Are" style="margin-left: 5px; ">
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="" class="label label-info">{{formfield.Field.label}}</label>
                        <textarea class="input-block-level" name="" section="{{formfield.section}}" id="test"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <h1 ng-switch-default>Error</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a link to a JSFiddle I was working on](http://jsfiddle.net/8geat/33/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to first group the fields into sections and then map them into something easily bindable in the UI.

```
$scope.sections = groupBySection(data);

function groupBySection(data) {
    var grouped = _.groupBy(data.FormsFields, 'section');

    return _.map(grouped, function(val, key){
        return { name: key, fields: val };
    });
};
```

And of course a [jsFiddle showing it all working](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/QwNNT/).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'd Upvote the comment but I don't have enough rep.